# nodejs - mongoose - create a document from json file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I save a mongodb document in a JSON file.

I want to write nodejs code to create a new mongodb document from this JSON file.

I tried 2 method, and both are failed.

1) If the JSON file has ObjectId("xxxxxxx"), the nodejs code cannot do JSON.parse() since it's NOT a valid JSON file

2) If I use mongoexport to export the document, I get something like:
{ _id: { '$oid': '5bf6e973180a93001bc5c895' } }, after that, JSON.parse() works, but insert failed.

Is there any other way to do it in nodejs code (NOT command line)?

---

I just think does mongoose has function, which take a String NOT a Object, to create documents?  If so, I do not need use JSON.pares() to parse this string.  Just read it from file, and send it to mongoose.

Comment: Do you need to store the `_id` in the JSON file for some reason? The `_id` property is a MongoDB construct and the database will automatically generate one for you if you do not supply one. You can find documentation for the `_id` document property [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field).

Comment: Not only _id.    I have other fields which are ObjectId() type.  Also, I have Date() type.  All the JS Object cannot be saved as valid JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that JSON does not support custom object types, only the primitives (Object, Array, number, boolean, string, etc.) are available in JSON. If you're storing valid JSON (as in #2) you could implement the `reviver` callback when using `JSON.parse()`. This will allow you to convert the objects into their respective class when they are deserialized.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

const json = `{ 
  "_id": { "$oid": "5bf6e973180a93001bc5c895" }, 
  "date": { "$date": "2018-12-06" }
}`;

const classes = {
    '$oid': ObjectId,
    '$date': Date
};

const parsed = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => {

    // If the key matches one of the classes convert the value.
    const Class = classes[key];
    if (Class) {
        return new Class(value);
    }

    // If the value is a normal object (e.g. not an array) look
    // at the first property to determine if the object is one
    // of the classes, if it is return the first property's value.
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Object]') {
        const firstProp = Object.keys(value)[0];
        if (classes.hasOwnProperty(firstProp)) {
            return value[firstProp];
        }
    }

    // Value does not need to be transformed.
    return value;
});
```

There are certainly limitations with this approach and the given implementation won't handle every situation, but it can definitely be tailored for the individual use cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I will try this.

Comment: The only thing I would like to mention is that the `JSON.parse(json...` shouldn't be given JSON but a String, so the name is misleading...